# What does "うちはどちらですか" mean?

Tags: translation, meaning, words

I am reading a little text, and I have some difficulties to understand. My Japanese level is far from JPLT5 to give you an idea.

This is the beginning of the text : (I used google to write so I hope there is no mistakes)

> ムスヤさんは写真家です。日本の山の写真をたくさん撮りました。
>
> うちはどちらですか。
>
> 長野です。長野で日本の古いうちを買いました。畳の部屋はとても便利ですから、好きです。 同じ部屋で仕事をします。食事もします。そして寝ます。ムスヤさんのお国はタンザニアですね。

This is what I tried to translate from the beginning:

> Musuya is a photographer. He took pictures of mountains from Japan.
>
> Where are you from?
>
> I'm from Nagano. At Negano I bought an old Japan..

Well obviously something looks to be wrong, I hope he didn't buy a Japanese.. well so I suspect `うちはどちらですか。` may means "where did you buy your camera" but there is not `買` in the question so I'm absolutely lost.

Can someone help me please. I would be glad.

Comment: Where did you get that text? Is it this one? https://www.koryu.or.jp/taipei/ez3_contents.nsf/15aef977a6d6761f49256de4002084ae/e998ad95446a7680492579df0027274c/$FILE/2010secondary4_ogata3.pdf

Comment: @siikamiika I don't know. I'm learning Japanese at School and the teacher gives us sheets  with text or lessons but they come from many support so I can't tell you.

Comment: @siikamiika I looked at your link, I have the half of that text with me. two first questions and answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your text is the same as behind [this link](https://www.koryu.or.jp/taipei/ez3_contents.nsf/15aef977a6d6761f49256de4002084ae/e998ad95446a7680492579df0027274c/$FILE/2010secondary4_ogata3.pdf). It's titled 「日本が好きです」 "I like Japan". It is an interview where everything after 「―」 is probably what Musuya says.

The beginning of your translation was about correct.

> ムスヤさんは写真家{しゃしんか}です。日本{にほん}の山{やま}の写真{しゃしん}を**たくさん**[撮りました]{とりました}。
>   *Musuya is a photographer. He took **a lot** of pictures of Japanese mountains.*

However, 「家{うち}」 can mean a home like here or just a house.

> 「**うち**はどちらですか」
>   *Where are you from? (Where is your **home**?)*
>
> …長野{ながの}で**日本{にほん}の**[古い]{ふるい}**うち**を[買いました]{かいました}。
>   *...I bought an old **Japanese** **house** in Nagano.*

As you can see, 「日本{にほん}**の**」 means "Japanese" and 「うち」 means "house" here.

The text after 「ムスヤさんのお国はタンザニアですね。」 is probably part of the next question to Musuya, and not related to the text before it.